ACF Inside Interactivity block
I’ve been using the WordPress Interactivity API blocks for a few months and have found them useful and straightforward until now.
BUT For the past two days, I’ve been trying to display ACF (Advanced Custom Fields) values linked to a post within the edit.js backend of a block. In this specific case, I need to rely on ACF because it involves passing complex data that would be difficult to manage manually.
Is it possible to display the ACF values associated with a post in the block editor part (edit.js), or alternatively, display the ACF field itself inside the block?
IN SIMPLER WORDS:
If I have a list of colors (blue, red, green, yellow) and my post has the colors "blue" and "red" assigned to it, I want to show these 2 colors inside the block
OR
Alternatively I want to have the ACF field to pick the colors inside the block (but where I can actually update the ACF field and not just create a side version, so I wont have 2 db tables for the same time with different values)

This should be a question for ACF's support channels as what you're asking most likely relates specifically to ACF.
